# Add the result from get-content command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of files in \log and in those files there is one line for each time the cpu on a certain computer reaches a threshold.

Each file is named after the computer and each file has a number of lines containing the number 5.

Right now my script counts how many lines there is in each file and the ouput is like this:

```
Computer name - PC000018.txt
2
............................
Computer name - PC000019.txt
1
............................
```

... but is it possible to add them up or multiply them?

Like if PC000018.txt has three lines like this:

```
5
5
5
```

then the output file would show:

```
Computer name - PC000018.txt
15 
............................
Computer name - PC000019.txt
1
............................
```

This is the script right now:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\log\' | ForEach-Object {
  @'
Computer name - {0}
{1}
............................
'@ -f $_, (Get-Content $_.FullName -ReadCount 10).Length
} | Out-File 'C:\temp\output.txt'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMExR.png)

I can count lines, but would like to output it with * 5. If three lines with 5, then the output would be 15.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to do something like below?

```
$template = @'
Computer name - {0}
{1}
............................
'@

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\log' -Filter 'PC*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $value = @($_ | Get-Content | Where-Object { $_ -eq '5' }).Count * 5
    $template -f $_.BaseName, $value
} | Set-Content -Path 'C:\temp\output.txt'
```

But... why not create a CSV file from that so you can open in Excel like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\log' -Filter 'PC*.txt' -File | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $_.BaseName
        Threshold    = @($_ | Get-Content | Where-Object { $_ -eq '5' }).Count * 5
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```